# Issue when parsing XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, minidom

I have been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now:

**I have an XML file that is similar to this (with 100s of entries)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<content>
    <email a="1" b="0">somename@somedomain.com</email>
    <email a="0" b="1">otherdomain@somedomain.org</email>
</content>
```

**My current code is attempting to parse through this xml file:**

```
 from xml.dom import minidom
    xmldoc = minidom.parse("data.xml")
    content = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("content")
    address = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("email")
    for addresses in address:
       Allow = True
       Block = True
       addressName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("email")
       getB = addresses.attributes["b"]
       b = getB.value
       getA = addresses.attributes["a"]
       a= getA.value
    #setting allow and block list values
       if (a == "1"):
         Allow = True
         print("This is allowed.")
       elif (b == "1"):
         Block = True
         print("No, you cannot do that")
```

**Right now, I am getting the following output:**

```
<DOM Element: addr at 0x3102850>
This is allowed.
<DOM Element: addr at 0x3102850>
No, you cannot do that
```

**My expected/hoped for result is:**

```
somename@somedomain.com
This is allowed.
otherdomain@somedomain
No, you cannot do that
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful.  I am still a beginner at programming, and am a bit stuck at the moment. I am also sorry if the formatting is incorrect, this is my first time posting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to print addressName at some stage which you do not show. It is a NodeList so you could try

```
print (addressName[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
```

But you already have the Node in addresses so you can just

```
print (addresses.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Stripping it down:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("data.xml")
address = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("email")
for addresses in address:
   Allow = True
   Block = True
   b = addresses.attributes["b"].value
   a = addresses.attributes["a"].value
   #setting allow and block list values
   print (addresses.firstChild.nodeValue)
   if (a == "1"):
     Allow = True
     print("This is allowed.")
   elif (b == "1"):
     Block = True
     print("No, you cannot do that")
```

But it is possible you have more than one text element in a different XML so you may need use:

```
   print (" ".join(t.nodeValue for t in addresses.childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE))
```

(Also you are using addresses when you should be using address and vice-versa but it is not causing an issue just harder to read)